# Последовательный запуск триггеров

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, триггер

При попытке вставки записи в таблицу `accounts`, над ней должно пройти шифрование и должна добавиться новая запись в стороннюю таблицу с содержанием кода вставляемой записи и ключом шифрования. Для этого я решил сделать триггер. Дело в том, что таблица `accounts` уже имеет триггер, который генерирует уникальное значение. Я указываю, что хочу чтобы сперва генерировался PK, а потом вызывался уже новый триггер.

Для этого я изменил триггер PK:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  ACCOUNTS_Triger 
    before INSERT ON ACCOUNTS FOR each ROW
    FOLLOWS trig_insert
BEGIN
    :new.ACCOUNT_ID := ACCOUNTS_seq.nextval;
END;
```

Код нового триггера:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_insert 
BEFORE INSERT ON ACCOUNTS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    p_key VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line(:new.ACCOUNT_ID);
    INSERT INTO ACCOUNTS_KEY VALUES(:new.ACCOUNT_ID, p_key); 
END;
```

На текущий момент у меня происходит ошибка, которая гласит, что поле `:new.ACCOUNT_ID` содержит `null`.

Как мне изменить код, чтобы триггеры вызывались последовательно в заданном мной порядке?

Comment: Уберите отдельные коды в отдельные процедуры. В триггере оставьте только обращение к этим процедурам в нужном порядке.

Comment: А если я уберу код второго триггера в процедуру, у меня поле все-равно будет null?

Comment: А вы порядок запуска не перепутали?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ключевое слово `FOLLOWS` значит -- "следующий за ...". Проверьте порядок вызова триггеров:

```
create table accounts (account_id int)
/
create or replace trigger trig1 before insert on accounts for each row
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('trig1: set new account_id');
    :new.account_id := 1;
end;
/
create or replace trigger trig2
before insert on accounts for each row 
    follows trig1
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('trig2: new account_id='||:new.account_id);
end;
/
```

Результат:

```
SQL> insert into accounts values (null);
trig1: set new account_id
trig2: new account_id=1

1 row created.
```

Comment: Можно вопрос не по теме. У меня во-втором триггере происходит добавление записи. Но на таблице, в которую добавляется запись, наложено ограничение, что первичный ключ является и внешним. Как я могу это обойти?

Comment: Можно, нo я не совсем понял вопрос. Вы имеете ввиду self-referensing? Может проще будет задать новый вопрос и в нём привести структуру таблицы.

Comment: Создал новый вопрос