# Вставка записи в таблицу с внешним ключом если записи с первичным ключом еще нет

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, триггер

Например, есть две таблицы со следующий структурой:

```
CREATE TABLE A ( 
    ID number PRIMARY KEY,
    TEXT varchar2(4000)
);
CREATE TABLE B ( 
    ID number PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES A,
    KEY varchar2(256)            
);
```

На таблицу A созданы два триггера (они приведены в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1120010/217579) вопросе).

Первый триггер генерирует `Id` для обоих PK. Во втором триггере происходит шифрование текста и шифровка должна заменить пришедший во вставке текст в A, а с ключом шифрования он должен вставлять новую запись в таблицу B.

Но из-за внешнего ключа на таблице В, я не могу вставить в неё запись с `Id`, которого ещё нет в таблице А.

Вопрос в том, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если от триггеров нельзя отказатья, например, потому что вставка с `INSERT` уже реализована, то такое *quick'n dirty* решение с [составным триггером](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-8A0DA171-BE6A-4798-A1A4-677B88EA16A0):

```sql
create or replace trigger triga for insert on a compound trigger
    key varchar2 (32); 

    before each row is begin 
        :new.id := 1;
        :new.text := 'XXX';
        key := 'KEY';
    end before each row; 

    after each row is begin 
        insert into b values (:new.id, key);
    end after each row; 
end;
/
insert into a values (null, 'new text');

select a.id, a.text, b.key from a join b on b.id=a.id;

        ID TEXT             KEY             
---------- ---------------- ----------------
         1 XXX              KEY
```

Comment: Да, так можно было бы сделать, но в триггере B происходит шифрование текста и шифровка заменяет пришедший в инсерте текст. Из-за этого нельзя использовать AFTER. Вообще я могу разбить это например на два триггера. НО хотелось бы знать, можно ли это как-то сделать в одном?

Comment: Мне кажется, что триггер вам не нужен? Почему вы ршили реализовать логику шифрования в триггере? Что не хватает, чтобы зашифровать и потом вставить?

Comment: Триггер нужен, потому что вставлять нужно уже зашифрованные данные

Comment: Не совсем понял, вставляйте уже зашифрованные данные. Триггер зачем для этого, что он должен делать, что нельзя сделать до вставки?

Comment: Например я даю строку Insert ... values ('Привет'), триггер её шифрует в 'FGUKDAS' и в таблицу вставляется уже именно эта запись. Поэтому и нужен триггер

Comment: Хорошо. Почему не так:  `insert A values ('FGUKDAS'); insert B values (A.id, 'KEY');`?

Comment: Как пока понял, вы хотите заменить текст в A на зашифрованый, а ключ записать в B. Это так?  Почему вы это ни в первом, ни во втором вопросе не указали?

Comment: А не подскажите, как в компаунд триггере, создать переменные, которые будут буфером между информацией before и after. Или есть какой-то вариант как передать данные из before в after?

Comment: Дополнил пример.

Answer (score 3):

Правильней будет отказаться от триггеров, так как [часто в них нет никакой необходимости](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/879249/217579).
Логику вставки как в вопросе можно тогда реализовать так:

```sql
create or replace type textRow force is object (text varchar2 (400), key varchar2 (32))
/
create or replace type textRows is table of textRow; 
/
create or replace procedure insertEncodedTextes (textes textRows) is
    type newIdRows is table of number;
    ids newIdRows; 
    targets textRows := textRows ();
begin
    targets.extend (textes.count);   
    <<encode>> for ix in 1..targets.count loop
        targets(ix) := textRow ('##'||textes(ix).text, '**'||textes(ix).text);
    end loop;

    forall ix in indices of targets
        insert into a (text) values (targets(ix).text)
        returning id bulk collect into ids;   

    forall ix in indices of ids
        insert into b values (ids(ix), targets(ix).key);
end;
/
```

Вставить пару новых записей и убедится, что результат как и ожидался:

```
exec insertEncodedTextes (textRows ( -
    textRow ('aaa', null), -
    textRow ('bbb', null)));

select a.id, a.text, b.key from a join b on b.id=a.id;

        ID TEXT             KEY             
---------- ---------------- ----------------
         1 ##aaa            **aaa           
         2 ##bbb            **bbb
```

Comment: А можете объяснить как работают оба варианта и как их можно модифицировать. Или где об этом можно прочитать

Comment: Какие два варианта? В этом ответе только один вариант. Он воиспроизводится (таблицы конечно надо поправить).  А что конкретно не понятно? Пример вроде не содержит каких-то новых или "магических" синтаксических конструкций.

Comment: Изменил структуру таблиц в вопросе. Обязательно проверте и поправте,  если что-то не так.

Comment: Структура таблиц верная. Непонятно от слова вообще как работать со структурами

Comment: Вообще по заданию, говорится об использовании только триггеров. Ну или пакетов. Сейчас попробую применить Ваш вариант с использованием триггера. Обязательно напишу о результате.

Comment: Если по заданию нужен триггер, то он есть в другом ответе.  _Непонятно от слова_ , от какого слова?

Answer (score 1):

Если без триггеров не обойтись, то в *oracle* есть возможность указать у внешних ключей отложенную до конца транзакции проверку целостности (ключевое слово *DEFERRABLE*).

[Статья](http://sql-oracle.ru/raznica-mezhdu-parametrami-initially-deferred-i-initially-immediate.html) для примера.